# Question about a line of reasoning with cyclic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, cyclic-decomposition

The following reasoning was used in a proof of the cyclic decomposition theorem by Hoffman and Kunze (for reference, part 3 of the proof, page 235).

Suppose $T$ is a linear transformation, and I have a $T$-admissible subspace $W$. We have some vector $v$ not in $W$, and we define
$$U = W + Z(v; T)$$ where $Z(v; T)$ is the cyclic subspace of all vectors $f(T)v$ for polynomials $f$ in the base field.

The idea is that we want to construct another vector $y$ whose $T$-conductor $q$ into $W$ is the same as the $T$-conductor for $v$, but we have that $q(T)y = 0$ so that we have 
$$W \cap Z(y; T) = 0.$$
If we use $q$ as above, there is some vector $w \in W$ such that $q(T)v = q(T)w$. Letting $y = v - w$, one can see fairly easy that $q(T)y = 0$, and since $y - v$ is in $W$ we have that $f(T)y$ is in $W$ if and only if $f(T)v$ is, so their $T$-conductor into $W$ is the same.

What confuses me is this. The authors immediately conclude that 
$$U = W \oplus Z(y; T),$$ where $U$ is as defined earlier. I'm not exactly sure how this follows from what's been deduced before. I think it suffices to show that $Z(v; T) = Z(y; T)$, but I have no idea how I would show that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $Z(v;T)$ will not equal $Z(y;T)$; luckily, you do not need the equality to hold. (If it did hold, then you would be able to just take $y=v$ always, which would make this whole development unnecessary).

Note that $W\leq U$; and by the definition of $y$, since $v,w\in U$, then $y\in U$. Moreover, note that $U$ is $T$-admissible (also known as $T$-invariant): given any vector $x\in U$, we have $T(x)\in U$. Thus, since $y\in U$, then $Z(y;T)\leq U$.

Thus, $W$ and $Z(y;T)$ are both subspaces of $U$, and hence $W+Z(y;T)\leq U$. Moreover, we know that $W\cap Z(y;T)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$, hence $W+Z(y;T)= W\oplus Z(y;T)$. The only question that remains is *why* we have that this direct sum is all of $U$.

The answer is that $\dim(U) = \dim(W)+\deg(q)$: since $q$ is the $T$-conductor of $v$ into $W$, if $\deg(q)=n$, then $v$, $T(v),\ldots,T^{n-1}(v)$ are linearly independent ($\deg(q)$ must be less than or equal to $\dim(Z(v;T))$), and are linearly independent from $W$. But as soon as you add $T^n(v)$, you get a linearly dependent set (since you can get a linear combination of $v,\ldots,T^{n-1}(v)$ equal to a vector in $W$). On the other hand, any element of $Z(v;T)$ can be expressed using $W$ and $v,\ldots,T^{n-1}(v)$, since given a polynomial $p(t)$, we can write $p(t) = s(t)q(t) + r(t)$ with $r(t)=0$ or $\deg(r)\lt n$, and hence $p(T)(v)= s(T)(q(T)(v)) + r(T)(v)$; but $q(T)(v)\in W$, hence $s(T)(q(T)(v))\in W$, and $r(T)(v)\in\mathrm{span}(v,T(v),\ldots,T^{n-1}(v))$. Thus, if you take a basis for $W$ and adjoin the elements $v,T(v),\ldots,T^{n-1}(v)$, you get a basis for $U$.

Now, since $q(y)=\mathbf{0}$, but $q$ is the $T$-conductor of $y$ into $W$, we also get that $\dim(Z(y;T)) = \deg(q)$. Thus, we have
$$\dim(W\oplus Z(y;T)) = \dim(W)+\dim(Z(y;T)) = \dim(W)+\deg(q) = \dim(U)$$
and hence we get $W\oplus Z(y;T) = U$, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Was it immediately obvious to you why the statement in my question above must have been true? Or is it not immediately obvious given the information provided above?

Comment: @JonathanLin: Given that I've **taught** graduate courses in linear algebra half a dozen times over the last fifteen years, I'm not a good gauge of what may or may not be obvious on first reading.

Answer (score 0):

When I was reading the same page, I had the same question.
I found that I can use equation (7-10) $\alpha_k = \beta_k - \gamma_0 - \sum_{1\leq i<k}h_i \beta_i$ to get the result. The key is to express $\alpha_k$ as some combinations of $\beta_i, i\leq k$ and $\beta_k$ as some combinations of $\alpha_i, i\leq k$ (by expanding (7-10) recursively).

Claim: $W_0 + Z(\alpha_1 ;T) + \cdots + Z(\alpha_k ;T) = W_0 + Z(\beta_1 ;T) + \cdots + Z(\beta_k ;T)$

Suppose $w_0+g_1\alpha_1+\cdots+g_k\alpha_k \in LHS$

By (7-10), this equals $w_0+(g_1\beta_1-g_1\gamma_0)+\cdots+(g_k\beta_k-g_k\gamma_0-\sum_{1\leq i<k}g_k h_i \beta_i)$

$= (w_0-g_1\gamma_0-\cdots-g_k\gamma_0)+(g_1\beta_1-\cdots-g_kh_1\beta_1)+\cdots+(g_{k-1}\beta_{k-1}-g_kh_{k-1}\beta_{k-1})+g_k\beta_k \in RHS$

The other direction:

Suppose $w_0+g_1\beta_1+\cdots+g_k\beta_k \in RHS$

By (7-10), this equals $w_0+(g_1\alpha_1+g_1\gamma_0)+\cdots+(g_k\alpha_k+g_k\gamma_0+\sum_{1\leq i<k}g_kh_i\beta_i)$

$=(w_0+g_1\gamma_0+\cdots+g_k\gamma_0)+(g_1\alpha_1+\cdots+g_k h_1 \beta_1)+\cdots+(g_{k-1}\alpha_{k-1}+g_k h_{k-1}\beta_{k-1})+g_k\alpha_k$

Note that $\beta_1 = \alpha_1 + \gamma_0$,

$\beta_2 = \alpha_2+\gamma_0+h_1\beta_1 = \alpha_2 + \gamma_0 + h_1(\alpha_1+\gamma_0)$,

$\beta_3 = \alpha_3 + \gamma_0 + h_1\beta_1 + h_2\beta_2 = \alpha_3+\gamma_0+h_1(\alpha_1+\gamma_0)+h_2(\alpha_2 + \gamma_0 + h_1(\alpha_1+\gamma_0))$, ...

That is, each $\beta_i$ can be expressed as some combinations of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots \alpha_i$.

Say $\beta_i = f_{i_0}\gamma_0 + f_{i_1}\alpha_1 + f_{i_2}\alpha_2+\cdots+f_{i_i}\alpha_i$ for some polynomials $f_{i_0}, f_{i_1}, f_{i_2}, ..., f_{i_i}$.

Then, that equals $(w_0+g_1\gamma_0+\cdots+g_k\gamma_0)+(g_1\alpha_1+\cdots+g_k h_1(f_{1_0}\gamma_0+f_{1_1}\alpha_1))+\cdots+(g_{k-1}\alpha_{k-1} + g_k h_{k-1}(f_{{k-1}_0}\gamma_0+\sum_{1\leq i\leq k-1}f_{{k-1}_i}\alpha_i)) + g_k\alpha_k$

$=(w_0 + g_1\gamma_0 + \cdots + g_k\gamma_0 + g_k h_1 f_{1_0}\gamma_0+\cdots+g_k h_{k-1}f_{{k-1}_0}\gamma_0)+(g_1\alpha_1+\cdots+g_k h_1 f_{1_1}\alpha_1+\cdots+g_k h_{k-1}f_{{k-1}_1}\alpha_1) + \cdots + (g_{k-1}\alpha_{k-1}+g_k h_{k-1} f_{{k-1}_{k-1}}\alpha_{k-1})+g_k\alpha_k \in LHS$.